# Can we prevent the browser to scroll the entire layout when the keyboard in open on safari iOS?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, mobile, mobile-safari

I have a layout with a div.header and a div.body with a form and some inputs inside.

The div.header is position absolute so does the div.body.
Both are at the same level, one below the other, have a height and it is possible to scroll when the content is larger than the height.

```
<div class="header">HEADER</div>
<div class="body">BODY</div>
```

So when the div.container has a lot of content, we can scroll the content. And the header will remain unchanged so it looks like stick to the top.

My question is on safari iOS, it seems like when the keyboard is opened after taping on a input, we suddenly can scroll the whole layout. And so the div.header shift up. Is there any way to disabled that ?

On android, only the div.body will be scrollable. And so the header looks sticky.